# Neo4j throw away part of match

Tags: neo4j

I need to run the following query in Neo4j:

```
Match (pnode:Node)-[r:NodeRel]->(to:Node) 
where exists(pnode.label) and exists(to.label) 
with pnode as pnode, collect({edgeLabel: r.label, neighbourId: to.Id}) as neighbours 
return ...
```

I need one row per node, with the list of neighbours. And it works. But then I realized I need that also the to node satisfies the pattern like pnode:

```
(to:Node)-[:NodeRel]->(to2:Node) where exists(to2.label)
```

To obtain this, i tried 2 things but none worked:

1.

```
Match (pnode:Node)-[r:NodeRel]->(to:Node)-[:NodeRel]->(to2:Node)
where exists(pnode.label) and exists(to.label) and exists(to2.label)
with...
```

But then the collect in the with clause duplicates all the neighbours entries (to nodes) by the number of to2 nodes and neo4j DOESN'T LET you use distinct in with clause (!!)

2.

```
Match (pnode:Node)-[r:NodeRel]->(to:Node) 
where exists(pnode.label) and exists(to.label) 
and (to:Node)-[:NodeRel]->(to2:Node) and exists(to2.label)
with...
```

But "to2 not defined" error is thrown.

I also tried this:

```
Match (pnode:Node)-[r:NodeRel]->(to:Node)-[:NodeRel]->(to2:Node) 
where exists(pnode.label) and exists(to.label) and exists(to2.label) 
with pnode as pnode, r as r, to as to, collect(to2) as n 
with pnode as pnode, collect({edgeLabel: r.label, neighbourId: to.Id}) as neighbours 
return ...
```

And it gives the correct result, but is painfully slow.

Any hint??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct` with aggregating function `collect`:

```
PROFILE
Match (pnode:Node)-[r:NodeRel]->(to:Node)-[:NodeRel]->(to2:Node)
where exists(pnode.label) and exists(to.label) and exists(to2.label)
with pnode, 
     collect(distinct {edgeLabel: r.label, neighbourId: to.Id}) as neighbours 
return ...
```

But in terms of performance will be better to distinct duplicates before `collect`:

```
PROFILE
Match (pnode:Node)-[r:NodeRel]->(to:Node)-[:NodeRel]->(to2:Node)
where exists(pnode.label) and exists(to.label) and exists(to2.label)
with distinct pnode, r, to
with pnode,
     collect({edgeLabel: r.label, neighbourId: to.Id}) as neighbours 
return ...
```

P.S. If the alias is the same as the variable name, then you do not need to specify it again:

> with pnode <s>as pnode</s>, r <s>as r</s>, to <s>as to</s>, ...

Comment: But as I said neo4j DOESN'T LET you use distinct in with clause ;) So i will go with first option

Comment: Are you sure that `DOESN'T LET`? On the test data, the second query works - http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qckb6y

Comment: Which version of neo4j are you using? The text of the error? The full text of the query?

Comment: i am even more astonished. now it works. thanks however